# find when $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} x^n \tan \left(\frac {x}{2^n}\right)$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

For which real numbers x is the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} x^n \tan \left(\frac {x}{2^n}\right)$$ convergent and how (i.e. absolutely/conditionally)?

I have proved that the series converges absolutely for $|x|<2$, since $$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|=\frac{|x|}{2} \left|1-\tan ^{2}\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}\right| \rightarrow\frac{|x|}{2}$$ and using the ratio test. Now I need to discuss the part where $|x| \ge 2$.

Comment: If the summation starts with $n = 0$, you have to think of $x = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. For $\lvert x\rvert \geqslant 2$, do the terms tend to $0$?

Comment: So for $|x| \ge 2$ we have $ |a_n| \ge 2^n \tan \frac{2}{2^n} = 2^n \frac {\sin 2^{1-n}}{\cos 2^{1-n}}$ which goes to 2 for $n\to \infty$ and so the series could not be convergent.

Comment: Yes, if you throw in a "for sufficiently large $n$". This inequality need not hold if $\lvert x\rvert/2^n \geqslant \pi/2$.

Comment: Note that the ratio test already covers $|x| > 2$ (you have shown the limit is $>1$ here so it diverges). The only case not covered by the ratio test is $|x| = 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|x|>2 $ then $$\lim_{n\to \infty } x^n \tan \frac{x}{2^n} =\lim_{n\to \infty } 2 (\frac{x}{2})^{n+1}\frac{ \tan \frac{x}{2^n}}{\frac{x}{2^n}} =\infty.$$
Therefore the series diverges